# Initially set all checkboxes to checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have jquery code that has the ability to set all checkboxes to 'checked' state on the click of a 'check all' checkbox. However, I would like to initially, start a html page by already having all checkboxes checked without having to click on that 'check all' checkbox. Please bear in mind, though, that I would like to keep the 'check all' checkbox since it has the ability to uncheck all checkboxes as well.

Here's my jquery code :

```
$('.chk_boxes').click(function(){
    var chk = $(this).attr('checked')?true:false;
    $('.chk_boxes1').attr('checked',chk);
});
```

Comment: `$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);` ...?

Comment: Or simply use the HTML `checked` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have all your checkboxes checked the moment the page is loaded without the need to click anything, use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").prop("checked", "true");
});
```

Or just generate your HTML input tag like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use html attributes

```
<input name="name" id="id" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

I wouldn't recommend using javascript to set these initial values because it will unnecessarily waste resources in the client machines.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your checkAll function outside of your click function, call it once the page load and when you click on the check all button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkAll(true);

    $('.chk_boxes').click(function(){
        var chk = $(this).attr('checked')?true:false;
        checkAll(chk)
    });

    function checkAll(isCheck){
        $('.chk_boxes1').attr('checked',isCheck);
    }
})
```

I also like @Univ approach.

Answer (score 0):

Change your original function to:

```
$('.chk_boxes').click(chkAll());
```

Create a new function:

```
function chkAll(){
    var chk = $(this).attr('checked')?true:false;
    $('.chk_boxes1').attr('checked',chk);
}
```

Call the new function when document are ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     chkAll();
})
```